# MySQL datatype for title number?

Tags: mysql, types

What is the best dataype in MySQL for title number for example X.X.X (4.3.1)?

Thanks.

Comment: seems `varchar` is what you need...

Comment: But varchar is not suitable when i want to list datas order by this field. It works with faulty when pass from 9.9 to 10.0...

Comment: faulty?  explain pls. I think it just returns what you ask for. perhaps your query is faulty?

Comment: asking a wrong question so I edit my question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683839/sort-integer-stored-in-varchar-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

`varcar(10)` should be sufficient.  Your "4.3.1" is 5 digits, so 10 characters would support an *additional* 5 characters.  E.g. "14.22.1740"

Depending on how large your version numbers might grow to (and then add a few characters to account for potential future needs) will depend on the length of the storage.  Google Chrome's current version (or at least, the one I'm running) is "47.0.2526.106 m" 15 characters.

*Comparing* these starts to get dicey, which appears to be your main problem.

But comparing version numbers has *always* been dicey.

At that point, I would suggest using 3 integer fields "main","major", and "minor" and sorting based on all three.

```
ORDER BY main DESC, major, minor
```

Comment: My problem is sorting with title number. For example when I use varchar and want to sort by title number that doesn't work when title numbers goes fom 9.9 to 10.1. 

My project about documents and their contents. I can not estimate how many digits that I will need in the future. Maybe one document has a titlewith the number 4.4.3.3.2.2.

Comment: Sadly that reduces to using varchar and having to write a stored procedure or similar in order to compare version numbers.  I am not sure how this might be done, only that it's complicated enough in a language like Java.  You should probably rewrite your question asking how to *sort* version strings in SQL rather than *storing* them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and helps. That is the main reason that why I couldn't find the solution on google. I change my question and search again. :)

Comment: I edit my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683839/sort-integer-stored-in-varchar-in-mysql